# Find all array keys which includes 'id' as prefix and rename them as just 'id'

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, iteration

I need to find the key names on an array that includes 'id' as prefix and change them as 'id' as unique key. There will be more elements  added from back-end to the array with id key names with many variations as possible.

1. First find key names that include 'id'.
2. Delete string that doesn't match with 'id' prefix.

Initial array:

```
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Name 01",
        "description": "Name 02",
        "createdDate": "",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "status": false,
        "idMapType": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "Name 01",
        "description": "Name 02",
        "createdDate": "",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "status": true,
        "idProjectStatus": 2, 
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Name 01",
        "description": "Name 02",
        "createdDate": "",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "status": false,
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "name": "Name 01",
        "description": "Name 02",
        "createdDate": "",
        "modifiedDate": null,
        "status": true,
        "id": 2, 
    }
]
```

Comment: I've removed your [tag:java] question tag since this question lacks relevance to this language. Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, that questions tags and question titles are the most important parts of your question, and that if either are off, you won't get the correct experts to see your question.

Comment: `const newData = data.map((item, i) => ({...item, id: i + 1}))` doesn't this solve your issue?

Comment: `[item[0].startsWith("id") ? "id" : item[0]]`